# Magento 2 - Customer/Token Rest API issue

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.3, rest-api, token

Customer is **signup** through **rest api** in **magento 2.3** successfully. after signup, I am unable to get customer's token through `customer/token` rest api.

Api returns following error:

[image]

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Muhammad, magefms is right 'all' shouldn't be there in URL and in devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html there is also the url without "all" key word

Comment: @Aaditya  `POST <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/integration/customer/token`. You can also this in devdocs in endpoint detail. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Yes totally agree /rest/english/V1/integration/customer/token I have Eglish store name which is working fine, Do you have store named "all" ?

Comment: and If you haven't configure then you can go with /rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token

Comment: @Aaditya that's the thing I am looking for. Nice point Yes It is for default. Now you got it

Comment: Great :) token is generated ?

Comment: Yes make it answer. I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For customer token if you want it store wise then you need to pass store_code in the API url

```
POST <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/integration/customer/token
```

But if you haven't configure any stores then pass default

```
POST <host>/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token
```

**And to fetch all store data using API**

> storeStoreRepositoryV1

---

**Group repository interface**

```
http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/store/storeGroups
```

- `method : GET`
- `Authorization : Bearer <admin token>`

This will return `website_id`, `root_category_id`, `default_store_id`, `name`, `code`

---

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `/rest/all/V1/integration/customer/token`
use this endpoint **`/rest/V1/integration/customer/token`** and you will get token.

Comment: It should be `/rest/all/V1`. check the endpoint detail in documentation. A combination of the server that fulfills the request, the web service, and the resource against which the request is being made.

For example, in the POST <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/integration/customer/token endpoint:
The server is magento.host/index.php/,
the web service is rest.
and the resource is /V1/integration/customer/token.

Comment: okay just want to share what works as per my experience